# what is the meaning of "retell" in this passage?

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of "retell" in this passage?

Over the years, The Lord of the Rings has met with widely varied critical reception. Tolkien intended his novel to act as a mythology for England, a group of fantastic tales about the prehistory of a world in which the values embodied those of the common British individual. Tolkien did not wish to **retell** existing myths or legends, but rather to create new myths altogether, beginning with wholly invented languages and shaping his stories around those languages and their cultures. This complex philological basis for Tolkien’s work, while inaccessible to most readers, remains distinct from the simple and universal themes of the story of The Lord of the Rings.

source https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/fellowship/context/

Answer (score 3):

It means what *re + verb* usually means - to do something again. He did not want to write his own version of existing legends ('tell them again'), but to invent his own new ones.